# Why does constexpr seemingly not imply const for char*?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, constants, constexpr

It seems obvious that constexpr implies const and thus it is common to see:

```
constexpr int foo = 42; // no const here
```

However if you write:

```
constexpr char *const str = "foo";
```

Then GCC will spawn "warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’" if -Wwrite-string flag is passed.

Writing:

```
constexpr const char *const str = "foo";
```

solves the issue.

So are constexpr const and constexpr really the same?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The issue is that in a variable declaration, `constexpr` always applies the `const`-ness to the object declared; `const` on the other hand can apply to a different type, depending on the placement.

Thus

```
constexpr const int i = 3;
constexpr int i = 3;
```

are equivalent;

```
constexpr char* p = nullptr;
constexpr char* const p = nullptr;
```

are equivalent; both make `p` a `const` pointer to `char`.

```
constexpr const char* p = nullptr;
constexpr const char* const p = nullptr;
```

are equivalent. `constexpr` makes `p` a `const` pointer. The `const` in `const char *` makes `p` point to `const char`.

Comment: are `constexpr const char* p = nullptr;` and `constexpr char* p = nullptr;` equivalent?

Comment: No, they aren't the same. `constexpr const char* p = nullptr;` declares that p is a const pointer to const char data, so neither p nor the data it points to can be modified.  `constexpr char* p = nullptr;` declares that p is a const pointer to char data, so p cannot be modified, but the data that p points to can be modified.

Comment: I think what @qbert220 wrote is essential and should be added to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The error message you're seeing has nothing to do with the `constexpr` keyword per se.

A string literal like "foo", as in:

```
somefunction("foo");
```

The type of this string literal is `const char *`. The following statement:

```
char *const str = "foo";
```

This tries to assign a `const char *` value to a `char *` value. The resulting `char *` value is non-mutable, constant, but by that time the error already occured: an attempt to convert a `const char *` to a `char *`.

The `constexpr` keyword in your example is just a distraction, and has no bearing on the error.

Comment: While true, I think the OP is right, it _ought_ to have a bearing on the error.  `constexpr` and `constexpr const` ought to be the same thing.

Comment: The problem is the conversion of a const char * to a char *. Whether the resulting value is a const, or a constexpr, is not a factor. The error already occured by that point. The same error will occur with just a plain char *foo="bar".

Comment: The type of `"foo"` is `const char [4]`.

Comment: You seem to be mentally attaching `constexpr` to the pointer, but I think it's attached to the characters.  I'm 100% aware that a string literal can't be converted to `char*`, but each `char` itself ought to be `constexpr`, and therefore a literal _ought to_ (logically) be assignable to `constexpr char*`.

Comment: Nope. constexpr is attached to the object being declared. The object being declared is not individual characters that the pointer points to, but the pointer itself.