# How to declare constant parameters in separate class or header file in C++?

Tags: c++

My IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

This is primitive example code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Klasa_00.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int const Number_0 = 234;
    float const Number_1 = 34.76;
    double const Number_2 = 98.78;

    cout << "Number_0 is:" << Number_0 << endl;
    cout << "Number_1 is:" << Number_0 << endl;
    cout << "Number_2 is:" << Number_0 << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Klasa_0.cpp

```
#include "Klasa_00.h"

Klasa_00::Klasa_00()
{
}


Klasa_00::~Klasa_00()
{
}
```

Klasa_0.h file

```
#pragma once
class Klasa_00
{

public:
    Klasa_00();
    ~Klasa_00();


};
```

I am new in C++ programing so I need a help about making code. For example, in Fortran programing language all variables with parameter attribute can be declared in separate module which can be easily used in main program.
What I want to learn here is possibility of using that principle of coding in C++ or something similar.
So, in my case a have a three variables which i want to move into class `Klasa_00`.
Is there way or ways for doing that?

Comment: Constants like yours can simply be defined in a header file, and then #included wherever you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you feel that you need a class for this? That doesn't seem appropriate. FORTRAN comparisons are also not likely to bear much fruit as C++ is a different language with different idioms and concepts.

To me, it seems like you should simply put those constants in a header file. Be sure to make them `static const constexpr` to avoid linker clashes.

```
// Constants.hpp
#ifndef MYLIB_CONSTANTS_HPP
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_HPP
#pragma once

static constexpr const int Number_0 = 234;
static constexpr const float Number_1 = 34.76;
static constexpr const double Number_2 = 98.78;

#endif
```

Now you just `#include "Constants.hpp"` in any translation unit that requires access to these values.

For the record, the old-school C approach to do the same thing would be to use `#define`s.

Don't forget to give these constants meaningful names.

Comment: They don't have to be declared static.

Comment: My intention is to learn also option with class. For example, I want to use class which contains also constant variables.

Comment: @Neil: Hmm, fair point. Though personally I still like to leave it in wherever, because the inline linkage isn't inherent if you move these into a class

Comment: @Judge_Dredd But if you want to learn C++ properly, you won't be creating a class that contains nothing but constants. That's not really what a class is for. You could put them in a _namespace_, and to be fair some people do use a class instead of a namespace, for some reason. I wouldn't recommend it though. If you want to create a class for some other purpose, then that's a different situation and a different question. Which book are you using?

Comment: I also get a warning message: truncation from double to const float.

Comment: Well, I will follow your suggestion. I am using now a book:

Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language

Comment: @Judge_Dredd, to eliminate warning just cast type explicit f.e. `(int)Number_1`

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Probably better to just use the right literal `static constexpr const float Number_1 = 34.76f;`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you might want to avoid using classes to store your constants in other files, and you might simply wish to store them in a header (possibly with a namespace, more on that later). Having said that, I do understand that you might want a constant that belongs to a class, so I'll cover that case as well later in the answer.

The simplest way is to declare and define the constant in a header on its own as such:

```
// YourHeader.h
#ifndef YOUR_HEADER_H
#define YOUR_HEADER_H

[...]
const int aConstNumber = 1;
static const int anotherConstNumber = 2;
constexpr int aConstExprNumber = 3;
static constexpr int anotherConstExprNumber = 4;
[...]

#endif

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "YourHeader.h"
int main()
{
    // You can simply access the variables by name as so:

    std::cout << aConstNumber << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << anotherConstNumber << "\n"; // 2
    std::cout << aConstExprNumber << "\n"; // 3
    std::cout << anotherConstExprNumber << std::endl; // 4
}
```

These variables all behave the same logically, but they work in different ways. A variable declared with the `const` keyword is defined at runtime, and guaranties it won't change. A variable declared with the `constexpr` keyword, however, is defined at compile time.

So, while this means that if you had multiple classes with something like an ID (which shouldn't change, but should be unique), you'd prefer `const` over `constexpr` (since the latter wouldn't work in that context).

Let's talk about `static` as well. `static` means that there is a single shared instance of that variable across your classes. So if the `Bar` class has a `static int ID` value, all instances of `Bar` share the same `ID` value. Changing it once changes it for all instances. Though if it's a constant, you won't *be* able to change it.

In your case, if it's to define constants that are pre-defined and won't change, I'd strongly recommend using `constexpr`, since you can use those variables to do things you couldn't use a `const` variable for (like defining the size of an array).

Before you go ahead and do that, however, consider the following class.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const int a = 5; // Valid use of const.
    constexpr int b = 7; // Invalid use of constexpr, won't even compile!
    static constexpr int c = 10; // Valid use of constexpr.

    int arrA[a]; // ERROR: 'a' is defined at runtime, so you can't use it to define a size.
    int arrB[b]; // ERROR: You couldn't even define 'b', so this is not going to work...
    int arrC[c]; // VALID: 'c' is known by the compiler, and is guaranteed to only ever be 10!
}
```

It is worth noting that if you wanted to access `a` or `c` (the only two valid variables declared and defined in your class), you'd have to use the following syntax, rather than just their names:

```
// "Foo" is their class' name, and represents their parent namespace.
std::cout << Foo::a << "\n"; // 5
std::cout << Foo::c << std::endl; // 10
```

As you can see, `constexpr int b = 7;` is invalid. Why though? Shouldn't it be seen by the compiler and work just fine? Well, no. You see, the issue is that maybe you'll never instantiate that class, right? `const` variables are fine, because they're defined at runtime, this means they don't have to exist, they just can't change once you've given them a value. `constexpr` on the other hand needs to be sure it'll exist, because it has to exist and be valid at compile time!

While declaring a `constexpr` variable is perfectly fine in a header file, it doesn't work unless you use the `static` keyword with it if you want to declare one in a class! Because the `static` keyword will let the compiler know that, regardless of how you instantiate this class, the variable's value will never change **and** it will be known at compile time thanks to `constexpr`!

I strongly recommend you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865842/does-static-constexpr-variable-make-sense) to understand just what `static` and `constexpr` do when combined.

- If you have "constants" that are only constant once instantiated, go with `const`.
- If you have constants that will never change and will always represent the same value (think of mathematical values like PI) go with `constexpr`.
- If all instances of a class should share a constant value, I'd recommend **against** using `static const`, since it would be defined at runtime, but it will always have the same value, right? Just use `static constexpr` instead.

Finally, I mentioned namespaces at the start of this answer. Sometimes, you might want a group of associated constants that don't necessarily belong to a class. For instance, while PI is used in circles, it doesn't necessarily mean that I want to include the `circle` class' header every time I want PI. But I don't want to have a "raw" PI variable name in my project's namespace! That's just asking for trouble. Instead, consider surrounding your constants in a `namespace` block to emulate the syntax used to call a class' member!

```
// YourHeader.h
#ifndef YOUR_HEADER_H
#define YOUR_HEADER_H

namespace MyConstants
{
    constexpr int a = 1;
    constexpr int b = 2;
}
#endif

    // main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "YourHeader.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << MyConstants::a << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << MyConstants::b << "\n"; // 2
}
```

Note that we didn't use `static` with a namespace, we don't need to since we're not using a `class` or `struct`, we're simply wrapping them in the `namespace` to avoid naming conflicts. `static` would do something else here. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406800/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-static-before-a-non-member-function) for more info on that.

Extra Note: While it is possible to declare a variable as a `constexpr const`, I wouldn't recommend it as it does the same as simply declaring it `constexpr`. Do note that `constexpr` when combined with pointers will turn the pointer into a constant pointer to a constant value! See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845058/constexpr-const-vs-constexpr-variables) for more details on that.