# Warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ for a static `constexpr char*` data member

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constexpr

Why does this code return a warning

> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’
>   [-Wwrite-strings]

if

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration or non-static
>   member function (until C++14) implies const. A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline.

([cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr))

```
#include <cassert>    
#include <string>    
#include <iostream>    

struct A     
{    
    // warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’    
    static constexpr char* name_ = "A";                           
    static constexpr char* name() { return name_; };             
};                                             

int main()    
{};
```

If I add a `const` after `constexpr`, the warning is gone:

```
#include <cassert>    
#include <string>    
#include <iostream>   



struct A     
{    
    static constexpr const char* name_ = "A";    
    static constexpr const char* name() { return name_; };    
};                                             

int main()    
{};
```

With `g++ --version = g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127`,

compilation `g++ -O3 -std=c++2a -Wall main.cpp -o main`.

Does the `constexpr` not imply `const` on `static` data members?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845058/constexpr-const-vs-constexpr-variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`constexpr` does imply `const`, but in this case it applies `const` to the "wrong thing".

```
constexpr char*
```

is basically the same as

```
char * const
```

which is a constant pointer to a non-const `char`.  This won't work because string literals have the type `const char[N]` so it would cast away the constness of the array elements.

```
constexpr const char*
```

on the other hand, is basically the same as

```
char const * const
```

which is a constant pointer to a constant `char`, which is what you want as it preserves the constness of the elements.

Answer (score 13):

There is a usual difference between a constant pointer and a pointer to constant. By making your `constexpr char*` you made a pointer itself a `constexpr` (and, of course, `const`), but it still attempts to point at non-const character - and this is wrong, as string literals are `const`. Solution:

```
constexpr const char* ch = "StackOverflow!";
```

Which declares a `constexpr` pointer to `const`.

Comment: I remember the rule `const` binds to the thing to its immediate left (unless its first, in which case it binds to the thing to its immediate right).  In my code, I tend to favor the general case, rather than the except-to-the-general rule in the parentheses.  `constexpr`, when I use it (not frequently), I always put on the left as the first thing.  I've not been bitten by the OP's situation yet.