To which variable does this constexpr apply to?
In the following expression:
constexpr char* master_lobby_server_address = "192.4.4.2";

Does the constexpr modify the pointer, or the underlying char values?
I ask this because const modifies the pointer only when it's to the "right" of the pointer symbol:
const char* my_pointer; // The char is const
char* const my_pointer; // The pointer is const

But it seems the rules for constexpr are different, right? Because the constexpr on the left side still makes the actual pointer value constexpr, right?
And so, the idiomatic C++ way to do this is:
constexpr const char* master_lobby_server_address = "666";

Which is the only way it compiles in Visual Studio.

I don't know the exact rules but I think a pointer to a constexpr is nonsensical so I'd assume constexpr char* does constexpr the pointer, not the char, yes.

constexpr is a declaration specifier. It isn't part of the the type (unlike const, which is), so comparing the two is comparing apples to oranges. All that connects them is that constexpr implies const, i.e. constexpr T is the same as constexpr const T (at the type level, not at the copy-paste syntax level). That works the same regardless of what T is.

Related / possible duplicate: What's the difference between constexpr and const? and What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258241/warning-iso-c-forbids-converting-a-string-constant-to-char-for-a-static-c/54258308#54258308

It is all a lot more clear if you just use inline constexpr std::string_view master_lobby_server_addres {"192.4.4.2"};  ;) That will also give you all the string comparisson operators you need later (without implicit conversions to std::string somewhere... or worse having to use strcmp)

@PepijnKramer You won't be able to pass it to C API then, which is a typical reason (one of) to use const char*.

@Evg I usually interact with different languages/technologies ("C", "COM, "gRPC" at the last possible moment (in an adapter layer) and keep the rest of my code as C++ as it can be. I usually need such a "layer" anyway because at these boundary points between languages/technologies I will usually need code to do "error/exception" translation also.  But yeah std::string_view can be a bit of a nuicanse since C++20 std::string + c_str() is a constexpr option too)
